# I have installed flutter SDK but i am recieving this error

Tags: flutter, installation

I have installed flutter SDK and extracted it in my C Drive and I even created ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES of both flutter and git but when I run command FLUTTER DOCTOR I am receiving this error can anyone help me please

[image]

Comment: Did you download git?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a needed program called "where" is missing, but a batch file is trying to run it. That's all I know, sorry.

Comment: what should i do now ?